# How can I reduce the amount of whitespace in a chapter heading?

Tags: fncychap

I'm a beginner in LaTeX and I've picked up a university template for a group report.

I can't figure out where I can change the chapter headings which have too much white space, both top and bottom. The template uses fncychap but I can't seem to find anything in there to change it. There's also a class file. Where am I likely to find an option for this? What should I look for? Can I manually override this?

For instance, our table of contents page is about a quarter whitespace at the top, which results in that it leaks out onto two pages which is completely unnecessary.

For starter's, I've gathered there are templates in fncychap, but I can't seem to figure out which one is used. This is the contents in the class file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%%  Fancy Chapter Headings
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% (must be loaded before hyperref)
\RequirePackage{./local/fncychap/fncychap}
%
% customizations
\makeatletter
  \ChNameVar{\raggedleft\Huge\rm}
  \ChNumVar{\Huge\rm}
  \ChTitleVar{\raggedleft\Huge\sf\bfseries}
  \ChRuleWidth{2pt}

  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \vskip -0.5\baselineskip
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip -0.5\baselineskip
   }
  \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 60\p@
    }
  \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 60\p@
    }
```

What is DOCH/DOTI etc.? I tried to play around with \vskip but it didn't seem to have any noticeable effect.

(The [Template](http://aerostudents.com/files/latex/thesisTemplate.zip) in Question)

Comment: This looks like a template provided by (or on behalf of) a university, to help students format their theses according to the university's style guidelines. If that's the case, I don't think it's a good idea to modify the layout defined in the template -- unless you want to risk getting your thesis rejected out of hand for failing to adhere to the formatting guidelines.

Comment: @Mico You have a valid point but this is a first year bachelor report so it's pretty flexible; the others groups are using MS Word :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is less space above the word "Contents", you can change the definition of `\DOTIS`. It stands for DO TItle Star form and it will be the first thing in an unnumbered chapter. If you put `\vspace*{-50pt}` just before \mghrulefill, that will cancel the 50pt of space added by `fncychap`. As an alternative, you could redefine `\@makeschapterhead` from `fncychap.sty`, removing or altering the `\vspace*{50pt}` line.

If you want even numbered chapters to have less top space, you can redefine `\DOCH`. This stands for DO Chapter Heading and is the first thing in a numbered chapter. You can start it with `\vspace*{-50pt}` for the same reason. An alternative is to redefine `\@makechapterhead` and remove or alter the starting `\vspace` command.

I would change the `\@make...` commands. The following simply remove the `\vspace*{50pt}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%  \vspace*{50\p@}% commenting out this line
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter%%%%% Fix for frontmatter, mainmatter, and backmatter 040920
        \DOCH
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \if@mainmatter%%%%% Fix for frontmatter, mainmatter, and backmatter 060424
      \DOTI{#1}%
    \else%
      \DOTIS{#1}%
    \fi
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
%  \vspace*{50\p@}% commenting out this command
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \DOTIS{#1}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Put this in your preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Answer (score 1):

The key to addressing the issue of reducing the amount of vertical whitespace above the fancy chapter header is to note that the `dutmsc` document class loads the `book` document class. As such, you need to patch two of the macros defined in `book.cls` -- specifically, the macros `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` for numbered and unnumbered chapters, respectively. (These two macros are both defined in `book.cls` and re-defined by the `fncychap` package, which is also loaded by the `dutmsc` class. That package's re-definition, interestingly, does not tinker with the default amount of whitespace above the chapter header, which is set at `50pt` by the `book` class.)

Add the following instructions to your preamble if you want *no* extra whitespace above the chapter headers.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % provides macros for patching macros
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{0\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{0\p@}{}{}
\makeatother
```